# Hibernate JPA: Unable to build entity manager factory

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, gradle

I have some issues setting up Hibernate to work with Tomcat.

Here is the project structure:

```
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── test
        │           ├── domain
        │           │   └── Person.java
        │           └── web
        │               └── Servlet.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── META-INF
        │       └── persistence.xml
        └── webapp
            └── META-INF
                └── web.xml
```

The `build.gradle` content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.2.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.4.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.30'


    def tomcatVersion = '8.0.5'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }
}

war {
    webXml = file('src/main/webapp/META-INF/web.xml')
}
```

The `Servlet` class:

```
package com.test.web;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

The WAR structure:

```
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── web.xml
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   │   └── persistence.xml
    │   └── com
    │       └── test
    │           ├── domain
    │           │   └── Person.class
    │           └── web
    │               └── Servlet.class
    ├── lib
    │   ├── antlr-2.7.7.jar
    │   ├── dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    │   ├── hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
    │   ├── hibernate-core-4.3.4.Final.jar
    │   ├── hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.4.Final.jar
    │   ├── hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
    │   ├── jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
    │   ├── javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
    │   ├── javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
    │   ├── jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
    │   ├── jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
    │   ├── jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
    │   ├── mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar
    │   └── xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
    └── web.xml
```

When I build the application with gradle, everything is ok, but when I try to access the page, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/Users/david/IdeaProjects/play/build/libs/play-1.0.war!/WEB-INF/classes] referenced by given URL [file:/Users/david/IdeaProjects/play/build/libs/play-1.0.war!/WEB-INF/classes] does not exist
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:73)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:48)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.buildArchiveDescriptor(AbstractScannerImpl.java:95)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:70)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:129)
    org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:93)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:86)
    org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:67)
    org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    com.test.web.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:13)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

I've absolutely no idea why it tries to load this file.